# How can I remove online accounts in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: accounts

I want to remove Facebook and Google from online accounts. How can I do this in Ubuntu 17.04? Other posts refer to much older Ubuntu releases. System Settings no longer has a delete button.

Comment: I don't have an easy way to do this, but I notice that at the point it asks me to sign in, there is a remove button.  However my username still appears, until I remove the directories `~/.config/goa-1.0` and `~/.cache/goa-1.0`, and reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Both Google and Facebook have a `Remove Account` button...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and execute the following command to remove the Facebook and Google plugins :

```
sudo apt purge account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-google libaccount-plugin-facebook libaccount-plugin-google
```

This removes the Facebook and Google online account plugins completely, right as I understood it from your question, which would be what you want to achieve. If you want to add any Facebook or Google account later on, simply reinstall the account plugins by executing the following command :

```
sudo apt install account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-google libaccount-plugin-facebook libaccount-plugin-google
```

Comment: You may wish to add a note that performing your answer will prohibit the user from adding Facebook/Google accounts in the future.

Comment: I think that we both took a slightly different angle on the question. I assumed that they just wanted to remove an existing Facebook/Google account definition (because they mentioned the delete button), and you thought permanently remove the possibility of adding Facebook/Google accounts all together. Without first deleting any defined accounts, your way might leave some dangling ends.